# Mathematics necessary for signal processing

Tags: reference-request

What is the mathematics needed to delve in signal processing?

I don't know if it correct to dig toward purism downwards or stay at the applied level. Specifically, in complex analysis I find the $\varepsilon-\delta$ definition and limits.

I don't know whether am going to use them for next concepts in the book or not. I found that the word neighborhood has specific meanings in topology and analysis. do I need some pure math?

Comment: Welcome to the site! You asked in quite rapid succession several related questions. It might be better to wait a bit longer for answers and feedback before asking a new question. If you want to expand or clarfiy a question you can [edit] them.

Comment: How deep do you want to delve into signal processing? Some engineering courses sidestep most theoretical issues and rely mostly on calculus.

Comment: to understand limits and precise definition of limits and neighborhoods ... convergence , conformal mapping ..etc

Comment: Is your choice of topics based on the answers to your question at http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/18280/study-signal-processing?

Comment: You may also wish to look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617625/on-familiarity-or-how-to-avoid-going-down-the-math-rabbit-hole on MSE.

Comment: @JW yes it's based on that post .. my final destination in signal processing

Comment: @JW i read the post u mentioned at your last comment, that's exactly my problem ... I can't deal with breadth first search as i like Every thing to be organized as i always used to see the whole picture and have no doubts about my understanding so what i need now is a prerequisite graph starting from the roots downwards , ending up to signal processing, i have no problem going all that path , but only if am sure am going in the correct way...so i need someone to discriminate the map...thanks for ur comments

Answer (score 1):

An important mathematical tool for signal processing is [differential equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_equation). Other necessary forms of math derive from this, including difference equations, transform theory, linear algebra, functional analysis, etc.